# How to fix the incompatible version problems in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json

I have a React application and I use Yarn to maintain packages. GitHub Dependabot was showing several vulnerabilities as shown below.

[Dependabot alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay0tW.png)

The packages that have these vulnerabilities where not available in package.json. So, I have used Resulutions to get rid of these vulnerabilities and it did.

```
{


"name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "6.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "handlebars": "4.7.7",
    "json-server": "^0.15.1",
    "kind-of": "6.0.3",
    "minimist": "1.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    
    // More Packages here
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "is-svg":"4.3.0",
    "ansi-html":"0.0.8",
    "react-dev-utils":"11.0.4",
    "immer":"9.0.6",
    "node-notifier":"8.0.1",
    "node-forge":"1.3.0",
    
    // More resolutions here
  }
}
```

Now, although dependabot is not showing the vulnerabilities, when I launch the application,
I get a ton of warnings (marked as errors) as shown here.

```
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "browserslist@4.16.5" is incompatible with requested version "browserslist@4.14.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "immer@9.0.6" is incompatible with requested version "immer@8.0.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^3.0.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^3.2.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^5.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^3.0.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^3.0.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^3.0.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^4.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "kind-of@6.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "kind-of@^3.0.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "tar@4.4.18" is incompatible with requested version "tar@^6.1.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "tar@4.4.18" is incompatible with requested version "tar@^6.0.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "ansi-regex@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested version "ansi-regex@^4.1.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "ansi-regex@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested version "ansi-regex@^3.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "trim-newlines@3.0.1" is incompatible with requested version "trim-newlines@^1.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "tar@4.4.18" is incompatible with requested version "tar@^2.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "ansi-regex@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested version "ansi-regex@^2.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "ansi-regex@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested version "ansi-regex@^2.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "react-dev-utils@11.0.4" is incompatible with requested version "react-dev-utils@^9.0.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "postcss@7.0.36" is incompatible with requested version "postcss@7.0.14"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "serialize-javascript@3.1.0" is incompatible with requested version "serialize-javascript@^1.7.0"  
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "ansi-html@0.0.8" is incompatible with requested version "ansi-html@0.0.7"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "object-path@0.11.8" is incompatible with requested version "object-path@0.11.4"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "serialize-javascript@3.1.0" is incompatible with requested version "serialize-javascript@^4.0.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "glob-parent@5.1.2" is incompatible with requested version "glob-parent@^3.1.0"
```

How do I get around this issue?
Is there a better way to use than using resolutions?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will often see transitive dependencies which have a vulnerability. To answer your question if there is a better way, you might want to go through each package and try to update it. Rather than just updating vuln dependencies with the resolution part.

Comment: Does it have any -ve effects if I leave it as it is? I mean the application certainly seems to be working fine. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I think you should be fine leaving it as is. Maybe you also stumbled upon this GitHub issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6301 stating that those warnings just verify the given semantic version. Which are probably from a transitive dependency and outside of your package.json control